# How to capture returned values from ArrayList Structure from Web Service

Tags: java

I am not a Java developer.Just some basic knowledge and understading.
I am trying to consume web service that I created and deployed it on localhost.
I created a proxy of the web service URL and it created all the Java classes.
Now I made a class to capture the data by passing in parameter and get return data in ArrayList.

My problem is now I passed in the parameters and I am getting values returned in Arraylist structure

This below code

```
CustomerLedger val = s.getCustomerLedger();
System.out.println(val.getDocVoucherInvoiceE()+ val.getDocumentPay() + 
val.getAmount()); 

s.getCustomerLedger();
```

is giving an error when I set CustomerLedger val = s.getCustomerLedger();

Here is the error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<CustomerLedger> to CustomerLedger

3 quick fixes available

Add cast to 'CustomerLedger'

Change type of 'val' to 'List<CustomerLedger>'

Change return type of 'getCustomerLedger(...)' to 'CustomerLedger'
```

I try the first option it is giving me Class cast exception
and second option is also useless.

Any solution for this will be really helpful. 
I would really appreciate that. I have been stuck on this for a week now.

I just need to know what should I do to have the last to lines of code working?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, the function is returning the list instead of one instance, so you can make below changes:

Old Code:

```
CustomerLedger val = s.getCustomerLedger();
    System.out.println(val.getDocVoucherInvoiceE()+ val.getDocumentPay() + 
    val.getAmount());
```

New Code:

```
List<CustomerLedger> customerLedgerList = s.getCustomerLedger();
CustomerLedger val = customerLedgerList.size()>0?customerLedgerList.get(0):null;
    System.out.println(val.getDocVoucherInvoiceE()+ val.getDocumentPay() + 
    val.getAmount());
```

So basically what I have done here is that I changed the variable of type `CustomerLedger` to a list of `CustomerLedger` and then fetch element at index 0. Here, I am assuming that `s.getCustomerLedger()` is returning only one element in the list. If it is returning more than one element, then you can change the `index` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Aman. The code didnt show any error but I what I see on console is this oracle.e1.bssv.jp55cl.MathNumeric@5aa9e4eb. Also there are multiple elements is in the list. I only see the first record. What can I do to see all records if lets see there are 100s of records in the list.